# Make a regex to validate string in particular format

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches my string with below format:

- Total there will be 10 to 12 characters in a string.
- And first 3 characters are distinct uppercase letters.
- Then the next 4 characters represent the birth year and will always be between 1900 and 2019.
- The next characters represent the number which can be either of these {10,20,50,100,200,500,1000}.
- The last character is an uppercase letter.

I came up with below regex but having issues coming up for my third point. This line `(1[9][0-9]{2}|2019)` looks wrong and it doesn't work for string `UYT20121000X`:

```
^(([A-Z])(?!\2)([A-Z])(?!\2|\3)[A-Z])(1[9][0-9]{2}|2019)(10{1,3}|[25]00?)([A-Z])$
```

After using above regex I will extract the number which matches my fourth point.

Comment: Try it like this `^(([A-Z])(?!\2)([A-Z])(?!\2|\3)[A-Z])(?:19\d{2}|20[01]\d)(?:1000|[125]0?0)[A-Z]$` https://regex101.com/r/uHCjPD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `(?:19\d{2}|20[01]\d)` to match the range from 1900-2019.

It matches from 1900 till 1999 or from 2000 till 2019

The updated pattern could look like

```
^(([A-Z])(?!\2)([A-Z])(?!\2|\3)[A-Z])(19\d{2}|20[01]\d)(10{1,3}|[25]00?)([A-Z])$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdmRY7/1)

Comment: @user1950349 Ok then you can keep the capturing groups. I have put them back.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^(([A-Z])(?!\2)([A-Z])(?!\2|\3)[A-Z])(19[0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9])(10{1,3}|[25]00?)([A-Z])$`

The format you want is either 19aa or 20ba

where a is any digit and b is either 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

Your regex only matches exactly 2019 from this century, not the range 2000-2019.

To match the range 1900-2019:

```
(19\d\d|20[01]\d)
```

Putting in your regex (and removing unnecessary groups):

```
^([A-Z])(?!\1)([A-Z])(?!\1|\2)[A-Z](19\d\d|20[01]\d)(10{1,3}|[25]00?)([A-Z])$
```